# add colorbar with yticklabes matlab

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I run Matlab R2013b

I would like to run a colorbar to my graph but instead of 4 labels as specified

```
figure
plot(1:100,rand(100))
hcb = colorbar('YTickLabel',{'Sleeping','Very light','Light','Moderate to vigorous'});
```

I get 6 labels: `{'Sleeping','Very light','Light','Moderate to vigorous','Sleeping','Very light'}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`colorbar` by default uses a colormap of 64 colors. That causes Matlab, by default, to place 6 yticks in the colorbar, namely at  10, 20, ... 60.

When you set the `'Yticklabel'` property, if you pass less strings than the number of yticks, those strings are cycled over. That's the behavior you observe.

The solution is to reduce the number of yticks to 4, so that it matches the number of strings you have. You may also want to use a 4-color colormap:

```
figure
plot(1:100,rand(100))
colormap(hsv(4)) %// example colormap with 4 colors.
hcb = colorbar;
set(hcb, 'Ytick', [1:4]+.5); %// 4 yticks, each "in the middle" of one color
set(hcb, 'YTickLabel', {'Sleeping','Very light','Light','Moderate to vigorous'});
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. I added some some empty labels...it's not perfect but acceptable.

Comment: For the default 'jet' colormap, you would use:   `set(hcb, 'YTick', [1:4]*64/5);`

Comment: thanks! Is it possible to still use all the colors of colormap?

Comment: set(hcb, 'Ytick', 1:round(64/4):64]); more or less is this what I want

Comment: would be possible in your graph to change the "size" of the color in the colorbar? for example the red should be smaller than the green...Red [0;1.1] Green [1.1 2] Blue [2 3] and Purple [4:end]

Comment: @gabboshow It can be done (but then placing the yticks is tricky). You basically need to manually define a colormap with, say, 2 repeated rows for the red; 5 for the green, etc. Then the red "size" will be 2/5 that of the green

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to also specify a vector `Ticks` of the same length, e.g. (syntax for R2014b, may be slightly different for R2013b):

```
colorbar('Ticks',[0 0.3 0.6 0.9],...
         'TickLabels',{'Sleeping','Very light','Light','Moderate to vigorous'})
```

Comment: this works for matlab 2014 unfortunately not for 2013